# Cheat for hidden game "Atari Breakout" in Google Image Search

Tags: javascript, html, firebug

How would a cheat/auto moving paddle in [this hidden html game](https://www.google.com/search?q=atari%20breakout&tbm=isch) look like?

There is a

```
<div id="breakout-ball"><span>●</span></div>
```

and a

```
<div id="breakout-paddle"></div>
```

when moving the mouse the paddle is moved horizontally. How can I connect the movement of the ball with the paddle?

*This question will become "community wiki" as soon as possible.*

Comment: This is a cool problem to solve, reverse engineering the minimised javascript now... I may be back.

Comment: @Yoda Just use the Force.

Answer (score 6):

```
function cheat() {
    var ball   = document.getElementById('breakout-ball');
    var paddle = document.getElementById('breakout-paddle');

    paddle.style.left = ball.style.left;

    setTimeout(cheat, 20);
}

cheat();

// Add this via the FireBug console.
```

Comment: @AdamArold I know, see this comment http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16532732/cheat-for-hidden-game-atari-breakout-in-google-image-search/16532928?noredirect=1#comment23765902_16533164

Answer (score 2):

I modified your solution slightly to account for the scenario of the ball going off screen and breaking the hack and also the ball getting jammed into the corner.

```
function cheat() {
  var ball   = document.getElementById('breakout-ball');
  var paddle = document.getElementById('breakout-paddle');

  var buffer = Math.floor((Math.random()*100)+1);
  var leftVal = parseInt(ball.style.left, 10);

  if (ball.style.left) {
    paddle.style.left = (leftVal - buffer) + 'px';
  }


  setTimeout(cheat, 100);
}

cheat();
```

To be honest though, if you are going down that road why not do this?

```
function cheat() {
  var paddle = document.getElementById('breakout-paddle');

  paddle.style.width = '100%';
}

cheat();
```

Anyway I'm going to continue to dig into the code and do some deeper manipulation

Comment: The 100% solution is really awful! :-)))

Comment: Btw maybe you find the speed multiplier? It's a little bit slow for testing ;-)

Comment: Good idea, although it is 1am here and I could see myself doing this until the early hours if I'm not careful, I will pop back tomorrow after work

Comment: The challenge I have set is to have the ball follow the mouse on x and y, should be interesting and challenging

Comment: The other solution by @powtac is actually slightly better IMO. Since it consistently collides with the left of the paddle, it completes the game faster in a consistent zig-zag whereas this is prone to inefficient block erosion :P
That being said, it can get stuck in the corner which isn't brilliant so I look forward to seeing the happy medium someone will have come up with by the time I wake up ;)

Comment: Its probably because the ball is constantly colliding with the leftmost region of the paddle, if a 50% offset is used rather than my crazy 1am "paddle wobbler" it may well resolve this.

Comment: When the ball hits near the center of the paddle, it flies off in a random direction, so you can avoid getting stuck without wobbling: `paddle.style.left = (parseInt(ball.style.left) - 80) + "px";`

Comment: Exactly as I said above, albeit in a slightly less concise manor. Does anyone have any insight on how to efficiently reverse engineer the 8k lines of obfuscated javascript enough to get a handle on some of the events? It's pretty painstaking with the approach I took last night

Answer (score 1):

in chrome, search the game, ctrl+J, paste the following in, and press enter.

This is a simple goal:

```
//get the ball's X position from its CSS
function ballx(){
    return parseFloat(document.querySelector("#breakout-ball").style.left.split("px")[0]);
}
function update(e){
    //throws an exception when the game isn't up. Can be really annoying.
    try{document.querySelector("#breakout-paddle").style.left = (ballx() - 75)+"px";}
    catch(ex){}
}
var intervalTimer = setInterval(update, 125);//let it have a single weakness in case someone else tries it while I am around.
```

The lower the interval rate, the faster the paddle will move relative to the ball, but the slower the game goes. The maximum rate can be given with a simple requestAnimationFrame cycle, but that slows the browser down a lot(at least on my laptop).

I tried changing the paddle's size. It doesn't really work.
I'm sure it would be simpler with jQuery, but why make cheating easy when doing it hard core is already so easy?

Answer (score 1):

I have come up with a new way to solve this problem. Whenever the screen size or window size changes, the paddle changes size based on the screen size. To combat this, I simply just added another section that splits the size of the paddle in half then uses that value to find the centre of the paddle. Very simple and very effective.

```
function autoMove() {
var ball   = document.getElementById('breakout-ball')
var paddle = document.getElementById('breakout-paddle')

var leftVal = parseInt(ball.style.left, 10)
var paddleWidth = parseFloat(paddle.style.width, 10) / 2

paddle.style.left = (leftVal - paddleWidth) + 'px'

setTimeout(autoMove, 20)
}

autoMove();
```

Also, didn't like the function name. It looks way too suspicious so changed it. Hope this helps.